# JavaFX custom ListCell inheriting behavior with index?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I have created a custom IntegerWrapper class to implement a property extractor method as below:

```
import javafx.beans.Observable;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class IntegerWrapper {

private IntegerProperty value = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
private BooleanProperty isListening = new SimpleBooleanProperty();

public static Callback<IntegerWrapper, Observable[]> extractor() {
    return new Callback<IntegerWrapper, Observable[]>() {
        @Override
        public Observable[] call(IntegerWrapper param) {
            return new Observable[] {param.value, param.isListening};
        }
    };
}

public void setValue(Integer number) {
    this.value.set(number);
}

public void setIsListening(Boolean bool) {
    this.isListening.set(bool);
}

public Integer getValue() {
    return value.get();
}

public boolean getIsListening() {
    return isListening.get();
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return new Integer(value.get()).toString();
}

}
```

I have also created a class called 'PortCell' which extends ListCell in order to design the cell to my liking as shown below:

```
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.control.ContextMenu;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;

public class PortCell extends ListCell<IntegerWrapper> {

private final Image IMAGE_OFF = new Image("/com/mswordhf/jnet/resources/error.png");
private final Image IMAGE_ON = new Image("/com/mswordhf/jnet/resources/success.png");

private GridPane grid = new GridPane();
private ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
private Label portNumber = new Label();
private ContextMenu contextMenu;

public PortCell(ContextMenu contextMenu) {
    this.contextMenu = contextMenu;
    configureGrid();
    configurePort();
    configureImage();
    addContentsToGrid();
}

private void configureGrid() {
    grid.setHgap(10);
    grid.setVgap(0);
    grid.setPadding(new Insets(0, 10, 0, 10));
}

private void configureImage() {
    imageView.setImage(IMAGE_OFF);
}

private void setImage(Image image) {
    imageView.setImage(image);
}

private void configurePort() {
    portNumber.getStyleClass().add("port-list-port");
}

private void addContentsToGrid() {
    grid.add(imageView, 0, 0, 1, 2);
    grid.add(portNumber, 1, 0);
}

@Override
public void updateItem(IntegerWrapper portInt, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(portInt, empty);

    if(empty) {
        clearContent();
    }else {
        if(portInt.getIsListening()) {
            setImage(IMAGE_ON);
        }
        addContent(portInt.getValue());
        setContextMenu(contextMenu);
    }
}

private void clearContent() {
    setContextMenu(null);
    setText(null);
    setGraphic(null);
}

private void addContent(Integer portInt) {
    setText(null);
    portNumber.setText(portInt.toString());
    setGraphic(grid);
}
}
```

When the user right clicks on a port number in the ListView and clicks 'Start Listening' I want the red cross to turn into a green tick which is all working fine, but when I remove the port above the one with the green tick, the port displayed below the green tick seems to sort of inherit the tick?  The green tick is only meant to be displayed when the IntegerWrapper being passed to the updateItem methods' 'getIsListening' method returns true.  It's probably something very simple that I'm overlooking but I am utterly bewildered, I've included a gif at the bottom to show the behavior I have described:

[Gif showing the undesired behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fyF9.gif)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `updateItem` you have:

```
if(portInt.getIsListening()) { 
    setImage(IMAGE_ON); 
}
```

All you need is an additional:

```
else { 
    setImage(IMAGE_OFF); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you it works!  I knew it would be something like that!  I feel so embarrassed haha!